# Fibration from homotopy orbits to classifying space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

I was reading the answer to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/836/do-homotopy-pullbacks-commute-with-homotopy-orbits-in-spaces

It seems like if $X$ is a free $G$-space, then there is a fiber sequence

$$ X \to X_{hG} \to BG$$

I understand that the map $EG \times X \to EG \to BG$ collapses all of the $G$-orbits. This means that it factorises through $X_{hG}$, which I suspect gives the desired map $X_{hG} \to BG$. It is also not hard to see that each of the fibers is $X$.

However, I can't seem to prove that this is a fibration. Any suggestions or references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a free action on $X$ since we are using homotopy orbits.

Pick a fiber bundle model of $EG \rightarrow BG$. Take local trivializations. Now if we cross the fiber with $X$, then we get a local trivialization of $G \times X \rightarrow EG \times X \rightarrow BG$ by again crossing with $X$. Now one may take a quotient by $G$. This results in the total space $EG \times X /G$ which is by definition $X_{hG}$. But since the quotient could just as well be taken fiberwise , we may also use our local trivializations and see that the result is a fiber bundle with fiber $(G \times X) /G \cong X$. Hence, we have a fiber bundle $X \rightarrow X_{hG} \rightarrow BG$.